# cursor adapter sqlite android version change

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am using tutorial of sqlite i have adapted most of the code to my requirement but facing single error of android version requirement. Basically my app requires min api 8 and following code of tutorial requires min api 11:-

can anyone help me to convert same code to suit min api 8??

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, R.layout.wiigsource, 
    cursor, 
    columns, 
    to,
    0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor that you are using is

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

which was added in API 11 you can use constructor

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

i.e remove the last argument 0.
A detailed description about the two constructors can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Edit:

But the above constructor is deprecated as rightly pointed out in the other answer. Therefore the best way would be to use

```
SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
```

and import the simpleCursorAdapter from

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
```

package